# Onclick PHP o JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Os explico mi problema. Estoy haciendo una especie de calendario con el cual al hacer click en un día, dentro de la misma página me abre el día seleccionado, diciéndome si es Lunes, Martes...el día en número y el año del día que he seleccionado.

Ahora estaba intentando hacer unas `>` y `<` para que al clickar me cambie el día a uno más o uno menos. En el calendario mensual también lo tengo pero ese lo hice con JavaScript, ahora estaba haciendo el diario con PHP, ya que al recibir la llamada de AJAX pues lo recibo con $_POST y me era más sencillo. Pero al llegar a este punto, creo que no podré hacer eso con PHP, y os quería preguntar si hay alguna forma de hacerlo o debo volver a hacerlo todo con JavaScript. Os dejo el código PHP que llevo de momento para que le echéis un vistazo:

```html
<?php
if (strpos(getcwd(), 'apen_files') !== false) {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
} else {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd().'/includes/apen_files/');
}
 require (_PS_ADMIN_DIR_."/config.php"); 
 
 //-----------------------------------------------------
 $any = $_POST['id_anio']; 
 $mesac=date ("F");
 $diaac=date ("j"); 
$mes = isset($_POST['id_mes'])? $_POST['id_mes'] : null;
$nomdia=date ("l");
$dia = $_POST['id_day'];
$date= "".$dia."-".$mes."-".$any;
$undiamas = $dia +1;
$undiamenos = $dia -1;
$unmesmas = $mes +1;
$unmesmenos = $mes -1;
$primerdiames = date('m-1-Y');
$ultim = date('t');

 ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/estilo.css"/>
<div id="principal_pordias">
 
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<?php $meses = array('',"ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE"); ?>
<?php $mesesing = array('',"January", "Febrary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"); ?>
<?php $dias = array('', 'LUNES','MARTES','MIÉRCOLES','JUEVES','VIERNES','SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO'); ?>
<?php function saber_dia($date) {
$dias = array('', 'LUNES','MARTES','MIÉRCOLES','JUEVES','VIERNES','SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO');
$fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($date))];
echo $fecha;
} ?>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php echo $any; ?>
</center></div>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php
if ($mes && !empty($mes)) {
    echo $meses[$mes];
}
else {
 echo $meses[date('n')];
}
?>
</center></div>
<p>
<div id="dias"><center>
<?php
if ($dia && !empty($dia))
{ echo $dia; }
else {
 echo $diaac;
}
 ?>
</center></div>
<div><a onclick="$dia +1">&lt;</a></div> <div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>
</script>
<p>
<div><center>
<?php
if ($dia && !empty($dia)) {
saber_dia($date); }
else {
 echo $dias[date('w')];
}
?>

<?php
$sinmes = $mesesing[date('n')];
$ultimodiamesant = date('t', strtotime($sinmes , '2018'));
 echo $ultimodiamesant; ?>

    <div id="fecha"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda , la verdad es que me he quedado un poco confuso al llegar a este punto.

Comment: te sugiero usar javascript, tambien podrias investigar o usar otras librerias existentes que ya tiene lo que buscas hacer ..!!

Comment: Como cuál? @Tegito123

Comment: La librería **[`moments.js`](http://momentjs.com)** podría serte de una ayuda inestimable para esto.